# What distinguishes dplyr::pull from purrr::pluck and magrittr::extract2?

Tags: r, tidyverse

In the past, when working with a data frame and wanting to get a single column as a vector, I would use `magrittr::extract2()` like this:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(wt_to_hp = wt/hp) %>%
  extract2('wt_to_hp')
```

But I've seen that `dplyr::pull()` and `purrr::pluck()` also exists to do much the same job: return a single vector from a data frame, not unlike `[[`.

Assuming that I'm always loading all 3 libraries for any project I work on, what are the advantages and use cases of each of these 3 functions? Or more specifically, what distinguishes them from each other?

Comment: I would use `[[`. If you like you could define `mypull <- `[[`` and then add `... %>% mypull('wt_to_hp')`

Comment: `dplyr::pull(wt_to_hp)` has the advantage of working with and without quotes, unlike the other two.

Comment: Also they give different results when you have an empty `data.frame()` (don't know if this is useful)..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you "should" use a function is really a matter of personal preference. Which function expresses your intention most clearly. There are differences between them. For example, `pluck` works better when you want to do multiple extractions. From help file:

```
 accessor(x[[1]])$foo 
 # is the same as
 pluck(x, 1, accessor, "foo")
```

so while it can be use to just extract a column, it's useful when you have more deeply nested structures or you want to compose with an accessor function.

The `pull` function is meant to blend in with the result of the `dplyr` function. It can take the name of a column using any of the ways you can with other functions in the package. For example it will work with `!!` style expansion where say `extract2` will not.

```
irispull <- function(x) {
  iris %>% pull(!!enquo(x))
}
irispull(Sepal.Length)
```

And `extract2` is nothing more than a "more readable" wrapper for the base function `[[`. In fact it's defined as `.Primitive("[[")` so it expects column names as character or column indexes and integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wanted to add that I noticed `pluck` allows assignment of values (e.g., `pluck(x, "col") <- value`) but `pull` does not.